# Extracting value from a list by name

Tags: r, string-literals

I have a list:

```
>data<- list("Apple"=12,"orange"=4,"pear"=5)
>fruit<- "Apple"
```

Now I extract the value for the Apple.

```
>data$fruit
```

I get NULL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data<- list("Apple"=12,"orange"=4,"pear"=5)
fruit<- "Apple"

data[fruit]
#$Apple
#[1] 12

data[[fruit]]
#[1] 12
```

As you see `[` returns a list whereas `[[` returns the vector. The former can select more than one element and the latter only a single element. You might benefit from reading `?"$"`.

Comment: Roland. I did do that, but I thought it returns both the name and the value, from what was displayed. I perceived it incorrectly. But thanks for clarifying that for me.